# Permission denied error while import to remote repository via svn

Tags: linux, svn

I am importing my project to another machine on my LAN to the directory:

```
/srv/svn/repos/my-repo
```

where my-repo was created via **svnadmin create** option

The permissions of /srv/svn/repos/my-repo are

> drwxr-xr-x  6  svn  svn  4096  2010-04-19 
>   17:30  my-repo

I executed following command to import myProject files to my-repo on remote system

```
sudo svn import -m "First import" myProject svn+ssh://baltusaj@192.2.12.133/srv/svn/repos/my-repo
```

This command started 'Adding' files but gave following error after 'Adding' 7 files

```
svn: Can't open file '/srv/svn/repos/baltoros-valgrind/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

Any idea whats going on...?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got it via a friend.

Giving write permission to svn on the directory 'db' solves the problem.

Thanks